# Как скрыть результат установки пакета Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

Вопрос в заголовке. При загрузке пакета, появляется длинный вывод, который портит визуальную составляющую ноутбука. Вопрос как скрыть вывод ячейки с установкой пакета?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как минимум есть два варианта:

- средствами самого `Jupyter Notebook` - пользовать соответствующую *магию* для ячейки:

```
%%capture
!pip install pandas
```

- средствами ОС перенаправить вывод, в частности для линукса так:

```
!pip install pandas > /dev/null
```